# Error deleting json object from array in Postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a Postgres table `timeline` with two columns:

- user_id (varchar)
- items (json)

This is the structure of `items` json field:

```
[
  {
    itemId: "12345",
    text: "blah blah"
  },
  //more items with itemId and text
]
```

I need to delete all the `items` where `itemId` equals a given value. e.g. 12345

I have this working SQL:

```
UPDATE timeline 
SET items = items::jsonb - cast(( 
  SELECT position - 1 timeline, jsonb_array_elements(items::jsonb)
  WITH ORDINALITY arr(item_object, position) 
  WHERE item_object->>'itemId' = '12345') as int)
```

It works fine. It only fails when no items are returned by the subquery i.e. when there are no items whose `itemId` equals '12345'. In those cases, I get this error:

> null value in column "items" violates not-null constraint

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
update timeline 
set items=(select 
           json_agg(j) 
          from json_array_elements(items) j 
          where j->>'itemId' not in ( '12345')
          );
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=b439c9b07de89498f266d4d31ed9cbaa)

Comment: Thank you! What about performance? Isn't this solution too heavy when there are many entries?

Comment: @Héctor  This answer is much better than mine.  The performance should be about the same as your original.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Certainly, it's more readable as well. Thank you very much anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when `null` is passed to the `-` operator, it results in `null` for the expression.  That not only violates your `not null` constraint, but it is probably also not what you are expecting.

This is a hack way of getting past it:

```
UPDATE timeline 
SET items = items::jsonb - coalesce(
   cast(( 
     SELECT position - 1 timeline, jsonb_array_elements(items::jsonb)
     WITH ORDINALITY arr(item_object, position) 
     WHERE item_object->>'itemId' = '12345') as int), 99999999)
```

A more correct way to do it would be to collect all of the indexes you want to delete with something like the below.  **If there is the possibility of more than one `userId: 12345` within a single `user_id` row, then this will either fail or mess up your `items`**(I have to test to see which), but at least it updates only rows with the `12345` records.

```
WITH deletes AS (
  SELECT t.user_id, e.rn - 1 as position
    FROM timeline t
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(t.items)
          WITH ORDINALITY as e(jobj, rn)
   WHERE e.jobj->>'itemId' = '12345'
)
UPDATE timeline 
   SET items = items - d.position
  FROM deletes d
 WHERE d.user_id = timeline.user_id;
```